# qt Connection of file reading with ProgressBar

Tags: qt, file, progress-bar

How can I write a file to a progress bar?

I tried this version:

```
    QFile wr(my_file);
    connect(&wr, &QFile::pos , ui->bar, &QProgressBar::setValue);
```

And this version:

```
    QFile wr(my_file);
    Qbytearray my_data;
    connect(&my_data, &Qbytearray::count , ui->bar, &QProgressBar::setValue);
```

This 2 versions above did not work
The second gives an error that `Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`  and the first gives
- `The slot requires more arguments than the signal provides.`
- `Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.`

How can I link the reading from the file to a progress bar so that I can see the uploaded file progress in memory?

- I know that the functions I have used are not signals, what I am asking is how to generate the appropriate signal / which alternative should I use to connect a suitable signal to the progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
class MyQFile : public QFile {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyQFile(const QString& filename)
        : QFile(filename)
        , bytesSum(0)
    {
    }    

signals:
    void progress(int value);

protected:
    qint64 readData(char* data, qint64 maxlen)
    {    
        qint64 bytesReaded = QFile::readData(data, maxlen);
        bytesSum += bytesReaded;

        emit progress((int)(bytesSum / size()) * 100);
        return bytesReaded;
    }

    private:
        qint64 bytesSum;
};
```